# Query on ApexPageInfo object to get created and lastedmodified fields

Tags: sobject, sobjectfield

From salesforce setup i can acle to see all visualforce page name,createdby,createddate,lastmodifieddate and some other fields, I would like to get all the informations by writing query on ApexPageInfo object but those fields are not available on this object. If those fields are not available in ApexPageInfo  object then where this informations are storing? Please explain in detail, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to refer to ApexPage rather than ApexPageInfo.

Simple SOQL query below.

```
SELECT CreatedById,CreatedDate,Description,Markup,MasterLabel,Name FROM ApexPage
```